# Input type="file" get a file from website instead of your computer

Tags: javascript, html, input

First of all i have two questions relationed with this.

First of all is using jsfiddle when I post my code in this website to make a demo it doesnt appear to be the same as browse it from my .html file. http://jsfiddle.net/93nLs6z9/2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script lenguage="javascript">
    function showMyImage(fileInput) {
        var files = fileInput.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {           
            var file = files[i];
            var imageType = /image.*/;     
            if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
                continue;
            }           
            var img=document.getElementById("thumbnil");            
            img.file = file;    
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(aImg) { 
                return function(e) { 
                    aImg.src = e.target.result; 


     }; 
            })(img);
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }    
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .upload input{
        display: none;
    }
    .upload label{
         background: DarkSlateBlue;
        color: white;
        padding: 2px 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="upload">
        <label for="my-input"> Upload your image </label>
        <input type="file" id="my-input"  accept="image/*" name="files[]"  onchange="showMyImage(this)" />
    </div> 
    <br/>
    <img id="thumbnil" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;"  src="" alt="image"/>
</body>
</html>
```

My main question comes now. I want to be able to have another buttom to be able to open a "art clipboard" with different .png images where the user could chouse instead of uploading a image from his computer. (this image should be shown in the new window as a previws image with less resolution).

Any advice how to start doing this?

Comment: Use window.open to show new window

Comment: The file input can not access files on your website. Basically you need to code something on the serverside to spit out the files in the directory and let the user pick one.

Answer (score -2):

there is a massive misstake here:

instead of

```
<script language></scipt>
```

you wrote

```
<script lenguage></script>
```

Also wanother button cannot be done

Comment: Does not matter, browser will ignore the unknown attribute and all will run fine. The language attribute has also been deprecated for awhile now.

Comment: And you have two spelling mistakes in your post. ;)